# Image not displaying properly based on date. JQMPHP

Tags: image, date

Here i have the code for a page that displays the events of a boating club. 
If the date of the event is before today's date, it should give 2 icons one which shows stats and one that shows result. If the date is today or after, it should display a calendar which can be used to save the date etc.

Here is my code:

```
        if ($startDate < $today && $endDate < $today){
            if ($startDate == $endDate){
                $p->addContent("<div id=truncate>");
                $p->addContent("<strong style=white-space:normal><a href='#'><img src=./aggregate.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>$startDate</strong>");
                $p->addContent("<p><br><a href='#'><img src=./race_result.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>                         $event</p>");
                $p->addContent("</div>");
                $p->addContent("<hr>");
            }else{
                $p->addContent("<div id=truncate>");
                $p->addContent("<strong style=white-space:normal><a href='#'><img src=./aggregate.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>$startDate - $endDate </strong>");
                $p->addContent("<p><a href='#'><img src=./race_result.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>$event</p>");
                $p->addContent("</div>");
                $p->addContent("<hr>");
            }
        }
        else{
            if ($startDate == $endDate){
                $p->addContent("<div id=truncate>");
                $p->addContent("<strong style=white-space:normal><a href='#'><img src=./calendar.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>$startDate</strong>");
                $p->addContent("<p>$event</p>");
                $p->addContent("</div>");
                $p->addContent("<hr>");
            }else{
                $p->addContent("<div id=truncate>");
                $p->addContent("<strong style=white-space:normal><a href='#'><img src=./calendar.png width=42.5 height=42.5 style=float:right></a>$startDate - $endDate </strong>");
                $p->addContent("<p>$event</p>");
                $p->addContent("</div>");
                $p->addContent("<hr>");
            }
        }
```

I get this. As you can see, it works fine until 13 October, and then it starts displaying 2 icons again. Don't know what i've done wrong here.

[image: problempicture]